# SSRS Matrix Dynamic Column Sort

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, columnsorting

Looking for a way to sort my SSRS report on each of the different column groups. I want to be able to sort my row group (a list of products) with a hidden field. The report is very dynamic, in the sense that the number of column groups changes every time the report is run and I want to be able to sort on each of the groups separately. Here is what my report looks like..

[image]

I've tried added the 'Interactive Sorting' property to the 'Day Supply' Column; sorting Detail Rows by Product Rank (the hidden field) and sorting Row Groups by Product Rank. Nothing happens when I try either way.

I have searched online and there looks like there may be a way to get what I want done using various parameters, but I haven't been able to figure that way out either. Any help or suggested would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to be able to sort on each of the groups separately? Do you want all "Day Supply" column to sorted in ascending or descending?

Comment: I want to be able to sort of each of the groups separately. So, for example if I click on the first 'Day Supply' column it will re-arrange my list of products to pull those with a higher rank to the top. Then if I click on the second 'Day Supply' column it will do the same but for that columns rank.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you use interactive sorting on the Row Group? I'm not sure if that's available there. I don't have SSRS atm to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below way in your Interactive Sorting (Day Supply), also delete the SORTING option available in your existing group (`Right Click in Group Properties > Sorting tab > Delete`).

[image]

Change according to your value.

Comment: I've removed the sorting on the column group and tried as you suggested; however when I run the report I get the error that is is an invalid SortExpressionScope. I even adjusted the "Apply this sorting to...data regions in" to see if that adjusted anything and it didn't.

I'm assuming that it might be something along the lines of what is explained in this article (http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3492236_7/MSSQL-Server-Reporting-Services-Black-Belt-Components--Ad-Hoc-Sorting-with-Parameters.htm) but haven't been able to figure that out either.

Comment: Can you please share the expression for "Sort By:"?

Comment: Pinwar13, 

No matter what expression I enter, if it's not "ProductID" then I receive this error.